# What is this TypeScript type doing?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, I'm working through a pretty intense Typescript codebase and I'm running into an issue. I can't for the life of me decipher this code. I'm fairly new to Typescript and this one just gets me for some reason.

I make a `JWTAuthPayload` `type` like this.

```
type JWTAuthPayload = {
  [Types.Initial]: {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: AuthUser;
  };
  [Types.Login]: {
    user: AuthUser;
  };
  [Types.Logout]: undefined;
  [Types.Register]: {
    user: AuthUser;
  };
};
```

Then I make a `JWTActions` `type`. This is the result of (I'm assuming) some mapped `type`.

```
export type JWTActions = ActionMap<JWTAuthPayload>[keyof ActionMap<JWTAuthPayload>];
```

And here is the `ActionMap` `type`

```
export type ActionMap<M extends { [index: string]: any }> = {
  [Key in keyof M]: M[Key] extends undefined
    ? {
        type: Key;
      }
    : {
        type: Key;
        payload: M[Key];
      };
};
```

Can someone explain how this type works and how it relates to the `JWTActions` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I moved your code to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygbwFBW1AkiASwBcCBDAGygF4oByfYs82gGixwBkB7AcwJGp1ufEK3bZhXMEUG1J0sTigAlYH2RFgAJ1mr1mrWIC%20GDPwMAzUgGNgUAILSAFgFVk29BhMYiiOwCkAdRhHIicABVI4ci5SABNBTCUAbXgkZAA6BhIKAF0ALk8lJQJkUKdQEmtSTTjCgCMuLnJgUhAAbnFisHctQvK3bU6lI2GcVL9M4X4CouLsHu1%2050GtMexRron0jPkiWbAQOOALfmA49ahtlAy9UoNZpPmoRb6HFd7Lzc2MYAAPBBcLQyXxIKBBELWEhcECoGj2KEEGEAWVICAAPBDypForE4gA%20ZIAa2AcC4FgciJRaMxwWxURi8XxuU6vwBQJBfkp0JAqIxyKg-00R1QaCu-GOf0KGi0-B4szacCgRnxiS2AGlSVB%20FASWSKcjZsjkpq4LlBX9hXFUIdjqcQOcugB%20ObzUHAQqmr5dQpPN1%20T2ky5KBAMvGFY2mlldb6dIA) if you want to check it.

First, `ActionMap` starts accepting a generic `M` and it is said that it should extend `{ [index: string]: any }` (it's recommended to use `Record<string, any>` btw).

Then the fun part.

`ActionMap` is using [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to generate a new type. As per the docs:

> A mapped type is a generic type which uses a union of PropertyKeys
> (frequently created via a keyof) to iterate through keys to create a
> type

This means that `ActionMap` is iterating over the keys of the generic `M` to create new keys in this new type, and this is this part:

```js
[Key in keyof M]: ...
```

Which means that if you use it like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQVtQIYC4oAjAexIBsJcA7AGixyMMQCcBLagc3oF8BuDBlCQoAQQDGwNiWoBZXGAA8sqBAAewCNQAm8KACUI4ki22LWHbnmogAfLZToG2ANoBpCCCgcoAa08kAGZQsgC6hNQArgC2RBAsAvyCwtCG8JHkSKgSUjLySnCItgJAA), for example:

```js
type Test = {
    a: boolean,
    b: string,
};

type ActionMap<M extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [Key in keyof M]: number;
};

type Result = ActionMap<Test>;
```

`Result` will be

```js
type Result = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}
```

In the example, `number` is hardcoded so you focus on the keys, not the type of the keys.

Ok, so Mapped Types are just creating the keys, what about the types for those keys? For that, [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) is being used. As per the docs:

> Conditional types take a form that looks a little like conditional
> expressions (condition ? trueExpression : falseExpression) in
> JavaScript. When the type on the left of the extends is assignable to
> the one on the right, then you’ll get the type in the first branch
> (the “true” branch); otherwise you’ll get the type in the latter
> branch (the “false” branch).

If we expand our example a little like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQVtQIYC4oAjAexIBsJcA7AGixyMMQCcBLagc3oF8BuDBlCQoAQQDGwNiWoBZXGAA8sqBAAewCNQAm8KACUI4ki22LWHbnmogAfLZToG2ANoBpCCCgcoAa08kAGZQsgC6hLLunqGqGlq6xGSUNFAA-FDUAK4AtkQQLFCEmToQgRwQ2gL8gsLQhvCZ5EioElIy8kpwiLYCQA):

```js
type Test = {
    a: boolean,
    b: string,
};

type ActionMap<M extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [Key in keyof M]: M[Key] extends boolean ? number : undefined;
};

type Result = ActionMap<Test>;
```

Now the only key that will have the type `number` is `a`, because it extends `boolean`. So, `Return` is:

```js
type Result = {
    a: number;
    b: undefined;
}
```

From your example, it's being checked whether `M[Key]` (or, the type assigned to the key, while iterating over the keys of `M`) extends `undefined`. The only case it does is when the key is `[Types.Logout]`, the type returned for this case is:

```js
{
    type: Key,
}
```

Which means that for `Types.Logout` the generated type is

```js
Logout: {
    type: Types.Logout;
};
```

Now, if `M[Key]` does not extend undefined, it will return a more complex type, that uses both `Key` and `M[Key]`. For example, for `[Types.Initial]`:

```js
{
    type: Key;
    payload: M[Key];
}

// becomes

Initial: {
    type: Types.Initial;
    payload: {
        isAuthenticated: boolean;
        user: AuthUser;
    };
};
```

Because while `Key` is `Types.Initial` (for this step of the iteration), `M[Key]` is the actual value, i.e. the type. So the whole type is assigned to `payload`.

All of this means that if you had:

```js
type A = ActionMap<JWTAuthPayload>;
```

Type `A` would be:

```js
type A = {
    Initial: {
        type: Types.Initial;
        payload: {
            isAuthenticated: boolean;
            user: AuthUser;
        };
    };
    Login: {
        type: Types.Login;
        payload: {
            user: AuthUser;
        };
    };
    Logout: {
        type: Types.Logout;
    };
    Register: {
        type: Types.Register;
        payload: {
            user: AuthUser;
        };
    };
}
```

But, in your code, you go a step further and you do:

```js
ActionMap<JWTAuthPayload>[keyof ActionMap<JWTAuthPayload>];
```

Which uses [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). As per the docs:

```js
type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean };
type Age = Person["age"];

// type Age = number
```

Which means that you can pluck the types by the name of the keys. If you provide multiple keys, you'll get a union type containing all the types. For example:

```js
type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean };
type I = Person["age" | "name"];

// type I = string | number
```

By using `keyof` you can get all the types from all the keys. Like:

```js
type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean };
type I = Person[keyof Person];

// type I = string | number | boolean
```

So, by using `keyof ActionMap<JWTAuthPayload>`, you are getting all the keys from the type I named `A`.
Then, by Indexed Access Types you use those keys to extract their types and combine everything into a union type. So, at the end of the day, `JWTActions` is:

```js
type JWTActions = {
    type: Types.Initial;
    payload: {
        isAuthenticated: boolean;
        user: AuthUser;
    };
} | {
    type: Types.Login;
    payload: {
        user: AuthUser;
    };
} | {
    type: Types.Logout;
} | {
    type: Types.Register;
    payload: {
        user: AuthUser;
    };
}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. Appreciate it. Stack Overflow Typescript is so low volume we need more quality answers like this! It helps learn it so much.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you for that. So just to clarify, `M` is an arbitrary name we give to some generic type for the map? Or does `M` mean something more in typescript?

Comment: @Mike single letters are a convention to signify a generic. To identify `T` a generic vs `SomeType`. But there's a movement about useful generic names going about too. Yes, it's arbitrary, like a function param.